# "Save to foursquare" venue id?

Tags: api, foursquare

I have noticed that the "Save to foursquare" misses venues even if I print basically all info I get from the API. Is it possible to add venue id to the vcard sections to make sure the "Save to foursquare" button points to the correct venue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/widgets for details on how to configure the save to foursquare button

Comment: Great, don't know how I could have missed that!